# How to get Automa.jl to accept input from stdin?

Tags: julia

I have some code which parses a string using [Automa.jl](https://github.com/BioJulia/Automa.jl).  I believe it simply travels through the string from left to right. My input file, which has only one line, is really large so I would like to avoid loading it all into memory.  As a result I would like my code to process the (huge) string coming from stdin but I am not sure how to do it. Here is my code (written by Jakob Nissen):

```
import Automa
import Automa.RegExp: @re_str
const re = Automa.RegExp

machine = (function ()
    # Primitives
    start = re"\["
    stop = re"\]"
    sep = re"," * re.opt(re.space())
    number = re"[0-9]+"
    numelem = number * (sep | stop)
    elems = re"[^\[]+" * re.rep(start | stop | sep | numelem)
    start.actions[:enter] = [:start]
    stop.actions[:enter] = [:stop]
    number.actions[:enter] = [:mark]
    number.actions[:exit] = [:number]
    return Automa.compile(elems)
end)()
actions = Dict(
    :start => quote
        # level > 1 && error("X")
        level == 1 && (inner = UInt32[])
        level += 1
    end,
    :stop => quote
        # level == 0 && error("")
        level == 2 && push!(outer, inner)
        level -= 1
        level == 0 && (done = true)
    end,
    :mark => :(mark = p),
    :number => quote
    n = UInt32(0)
    @inbounds for i in mark:p-1
        n = n * 10 + UInt32(data[i] - 0x30)
    end
    push!(inner, n)
end
)
context = Automa.CodeGenContext()
@eval function parsestring(data::Union{String,Vector{UInt8}})
    mark = 0
    level = 0
    done = false
    inner = UInt32[]
    outer = Vector{UInt32}[]
    $(Automa.generate_init_code(context, machine))
    p_end = p_eof = lastindex(data)
    $(Automa.generate_exec_code(context, machine, actions))
    if (cs != 0) & (!done)
        error("failed to parse on byte ", p)
    end
    return outer
end
```

How can you change this so that parsestring accepts a string coming from stdin?

Comment: I guess the "inner arrays" are potentially unbounded, so that you can't just split off chunks and feed them to the parser as strings? Alternative: use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) to transform your array-of-arrays in to a reasonable space-and-newline format.

Comment: @phipsgabler There are 4 inner arrays between the first [[ and first ]]. Those are all that I care about even though the string has text before and after it. Each inner array has exactly the same number of numbers in it and I know what that is. I don't want to read in an entire inner array into RAM either if I can avoid it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then my ideas are useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My input file, which has only one line, is really large so I would like to avoid loading it all into memory.

You can mmap it

```
using MMap
Mmap.mmap(file)
```

and pass the resulting `Vector{UInt8}` to `parsestring`.

> How can you change this so that parsestring accepts a string coming from stdin?

`stdin` is a stream so you would need `parsestring` to be able to accept an `IO` object.

Comment: Thank you. I will have to work out how to use an IO object.